# Java C integration using message queue

Tags: java, c, message-queue

I have java program which receives encrypted message through TCP/IP from one component of the system.It has to send this message to a HSM (Hardware Security Module) which will decrypt the message. Now this HSM talks C as far as I know.I am thinking of putting a Message Queue in between where Java program will put text message. C program will pick the message from message queue and send to HSM.
Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write a c function to access the HSM and call it via Java Native Interface (JNI).  Here is a link to a Sun [JNI Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html).